# Rules for chanting Oṃ namo bhagavate Vāsudevāya

Tags: krishna, belief, mantras

Is there any rule for chanting Mahamantra :-

```
Oṃ namo bhagavate Vāsudevāya
```

Or can any one chant this anywhere at anytime (while travelling, eating, sleeping, resting on bed) as we can do nama smarana(taking name of lord).

Comment: If u are serious then u have to find for urself a Guruji who can initiate u into this mantra..Then chant as much as u like without any fears...

Comment: I believe it needs to be given to you by a guru. They will instruct on the rules as well.

Comment: Pranava (the sound before 'namo') should not be chanted by anyone/anytime/anyplace.. it is to be respected greatly, that even when saying "do not chant <pranava>, we are not supposed to say it out loud". Also, Narada imparted this mantra to Dhruva. Similarly a guru must impart to you. He will decide based on your character if you are fit to receive it. You may ask why? Because, whenever a Guru initiates a disciple into a mantra, he formally accepts the sins you will commit in future. Because, the effect of mantra will save you, so someone else has to take the blame for your deeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who can chanta the mantra

**Any Sincere Vaishnava can chant it regardless of caste creed or sex**

The mantra Om Namo Bhagwate Vasudevaya is very first verse of [Shrimad Bhagwatam](https://www.vedabase.com/sb/1/1/1), Shrimad Bhagwatam is a smriti, so there are no restrictions on who is eligible to recite.

The mantra is open to all, and anyone who is sincere Vaishanva can recite(do japa) it.

> Or can any one chant this anywhere at anytime (while travelling, eating , Slipping , resting on bed) as we can do namasmaran.

The basic rules of japa must be followed, Vaishnava means one who has tan(body),mana(mind), atman(soul) everything dedicated or surrendered to Shriman Narayana.

A Vaishnava must maintain sattva, it can be maintained by sattvik food and everyday life discipline is must.

[Categorization of food items](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2660/489)

**Everyday life discipline** includes a specific place to chant(clean, neither too hot nor too cold, noise free zone) must be chosen, an asana of choice mostly kusha asana.

**Bodily discipline** basic sanitation, regular bathing, and [achmana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16465/48), celibacy, and following Dharma as in Dharma Shastras.

**Time discipline** Since I don't follow it I cannot comment on it, but one thing for sure [sandhya kala](http://sanatanavenkat.blogspot.in/2007/11/sandhyavandanam-time.html) and [bramha muhurata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmamuhurtha) are best timings

For travelling only bodily discipline is enough(while travelling even Dwijas are exempted from doing Sandhyavandanam).

Resting on bed : no, sleeping no, eating: yes(if you follow food discipline and eat prasadam, then food is ambrosia)

Comment: Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya is both Puranaic and Tantrik Mantra. Also, what scriptures talk these rules? Also, you should define who is Vaishnava? I think everyone can chant this mantra not only Vaishnavas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Anyone who accepts that Shriman Narayana is the only saviour is a Vaishnava, anyone who trusts Shriman Narayana will chant it so He is certainly a Vaishnava. All Vaishnava sect focus on maintenance of sattva. Bodily disciple is to be maintained by everybody it is nitya saucha(regular cleanliness). Regarding prasadam BG chapter 3 krishna says that one who eats food without offering it to gods is a sinner and verily eats sin.

Comment: I don't think this mantra can be chanted by only vaishnavas. Anyways, can you cite sources for your statements, "The mantra is open to all, and anyone who is **sincere Vaishanva** can recite(do japa) it.", "The basic rules of japa must be followed.."  and other rules pertaining to **this mantra**.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Smritis don't have eligibility restrictions only basic niymas from dharma shastras must be followed.

Comment: But, as a site policy, one should cite sources for all statements. Hope you understand :)

Comment: Who told you anyone can chant the Pranava (OM)? It requires initiation..Pranava is the Nada-Brahman...

Comment: This generic statement like any can chant all are equal  its funny to hear

Answer (score 6):

One of the powerful mantras of Vishnu is the dwadashaksra mantra or the  `Om namo bhagavate vasudevaya` mantra.

It can be taken only from a Guru. One can't simply start chanting it by taking it from a book. That is a sin as per scriptures. And, this is valid for not just for this mantra but for every other mantras too.

The Vaisnava Agama shastras provide the following procedures for chanting this mantra:

> Atha VAsudeva Mantrah : Pranavo Hritbhagavate VAsudevAya Kirtitah |
>   PradhAne Vaisha Ve Tantre Mantrohaya SurapAdapah |
>
> .......................................
>
> Om namo bhagavate vAsudevaya, this 12-lettered mantra is
>   "kalpapAdapa-swarupa" that is,  japa of this mantra fulfills all
>   desires of the sadhaka.

Then the procedure for pithanyasa, rishyadi nyasa, kara-anga nyasas are laid down:

> Yatha sirasi prajapataye rishaye namah, mukhe gayatricchandase namaha,
>   hrudi vAsudevAya devatayai namaha.

The above rishyadi nyasas give the rishi, chanda and devata of the mantra as prajapati , gayatri and vasudeva respectively.

Then comes kara (hands) and anga (parts of body) nyasas which are done like this ( I am intentionally omitting almost all mantras & giving only a few as  samples as the full procedure should only be learned from the GUru) :

> Om angushtabhyAm namha |
>  namastarjanibhyAm swAhA |
>  bhagavate
>   madhyamAbhyAm vashata etc etc...

Then the sadhaka has to do anga nyasa with prescribed mantras given in Agamas.

After that comes mantra nyasa, where the devotee plants the 12 letters of the mantra on different parts of his body using prescribed mudras and mantras.

After that comes the dhyana part where the devotee chants the dhyana sloka for Vasudeva. Thereafter manasa puja is done by the sadhaka.

After that the sadhaka has to do pitha puja with Vishnu mantras and etc.

This mantra's purascharana is done  by 12 lakh japas and 12,000 homas.

> Asya Purascharanam **DwAdasalakshyajapaha**

Although  after completing one lakh japa only a devotee attains jitendriyata or victory over senses.

> Varna Laksham Japenmantram **Dikshito**vijitendriyoho .

Also, note that in the above verse its stated about the **dikshito** or one who is initiated. **Now this clearly indicates that only initiated person is allowed to chant the mantra.**

In any case, pranava or OM should not be chanted without initiation. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31621/4732) for example.

So, in short, many rules are there for chanting this mantra and for every other mantras. And if you are genuinely interested in learning them , then initiation is the only method.

Source - The verses from Vaishnava Agamas as quoted in the compendium [Brihat Tantrasara.](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm)

Comment: Which Pancharatra Agama is this from?  For the record I agree with you answer; the Pranava definitely requires Upanayana.

Comment: Sir Chinna Jiyar Swami has said Sudras and Mechlas also can chant Om Namo Narayan after Diksha. May be Vaishava Agamas allow Om to be chanted together sir...Else why will so many Sri Vaishnavas do so?I know we discussed this already but still...

Answer (score 2):

A mantra should be taken from a Guru. If you read it and started chanting is good but dont stop there. Keep chanting it  but meanwhile seek some good Guru who can give you an authentic diksha of this mantra. There are rules of place, hygiene time etc. for japa on a rosary but there are no rules for mansik japa(reciting mantra in mind only without using a rosary). A japa is compared to a Yagya(sacred fire). God says in Geeta that '

> 'Yagyanam japayagyo asmi'

Japa is a Yagya where the one who chants burns his Agyana and Papa Karmas.

> If you wish to experience the effects of japa do an Anushthana. Multiply the number of letters in a mantra by 1 lac. You will get a number. Chanting the mantra for that much time completes the Anushthana.
>
> One should take a saltless diet during an Anushthana ,must sleep on a floor, observe silence and follow celibacy.

Hope this helps. May lord Vishnu bless us! :)