# Dwadakshari vs. Ashtakshari mantra of Sriman Narayana

Tags: vishnu, mantras

Is there any difference in applicability between the mantras "Om namo baghavate vasudevaaya" vs. "Om namo narayanaya"? Is there a superior among these 2 mantras? And which one can be recited by the un-initiated?

Comment: Finding the superior mantra and the greatest mantra etc., gives rise to primarily opinion based answers and who can recite the mantra is a duplicate of old questions.

Comment: Which is the panchakshari here?

Comment: Sorry i must have said 'dwadasakshari' - only realized after posting topic. Also, when posting topic, no match turned up. That is why question on who can recite.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question! The Q is valid and it can be answered according to the scripture, namely perhaps some scripture may have said some mantra is superior to some other mantra. By the way, some scripture says some mantras are superior to some other, this is not uncommon.

Comment: @JRD you seem to have logged in as a guest and hence you've created two accounts. Delete the new one and log in to your previous account.

Comment: I just logged in from cellphone day before yesterday. I entered the same username (JRD) and my email address. How do I delete the new account?

Comment: Even though it can be answered, it is better to remove the part which is opinion based. Finding a mantra which is superior is not a wise thing and it takes you backward not forward. For initiated part. it is answered here. [https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17498/5212](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17498/5212) . The ashtakshari _must not_ be chanted without initiation. It requires initiation. Any mantra must be taken as upadesha.

Answer (score 1):

That mantra is best which we find mentally repeating without our being aware of our action. In fact all mantras are oriented to serve the purpose of taking sadhaka to his inner consciousness where God resides who is nameless and formless.