# Is chanting “OM” naam japa or mantra japa?

Tags: mantras, om, initiation, japa, nama-japa

1. does one need some form of Diksha to chant OM or can it be chanted by anyone?
2. Are there any benefits of simply chanting OM?

Comment: Keep chanting OM all time... just see miracles happening afterwards

Comment: It is said only Sanyasis should chant OM not Grihasthas.

Comment: but there are different types of chanting if you chant OM in one matra anybody can do. if you do in 3 matra.. its for sanyasi, It will lead to virakthi..

Answer (score 9):

**Om is a Mantra**, so chanting Om constitutes Mantra Japa. Other names for it are Pranava Mantra, TAraka Mantra etc.

Om represents the Adi Dvani (primordial sound) and is an Ekakshara Bija Mantra (mono-syllabled seed Mantra). It also represents the Brahman in the MAntrik level.

> EkAkshare tathA kute traipure mantra nAyike |
>  Shtri datte swapna
>   lavdhe cha sidhhAdi naiva sAdhayet ||
>
> O MantranAyika! - For mono-syllabled Mantras, Kuta Mantras, Tripura
>   Mantras and those which are women-given (given by StriGurus) or those which are
>   obtained in dreams, considerations like SiddhAdi are not required.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 15.98**

The above verse says that for all mono-syllabled Mantras Siddha-Asiddha and other such considerations are not required (usually they are required for Mantras).

This verse proves that Ekakshara Mantras are Mantras.

Few examples of such Mantras (besides Om) are Hrim (Shakti Bija), Srim (Lakshmi Bija), Klim (KAma Bija), Aim (VAg Bija), Hum, Haum (Shiva Bija), Gam (Ganapaty), Dum (DurgA) etc etc.

And, Om definitely requires initiation.

> **EkAkshmarapradAtAram** yo gurunchA vamanayet |
>  SwAnam yoni satam gatvA chandAlatvam vApnuyAt ||
>
> One who insults the Guru, **who is the giver of ekAkshara (or OM)**,
>   gets the womb of dogs for hundred births and thereafter gets
>   chandAla-hood (a low human birth).
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 11.74.**

So, Guru is the one who gives the initiation of Om.

Also, in all scriptures, including the Tantras, there are certain restrictions regarding the initiation of Om.

> SwAhA Pranava Samyuktam Sudre Mantram Dadad DvijAh |
>  Sudro
>   NirayagAmi SyAd BrAhamano YAtyadhogatim ||
>
> The Brahmin who gives a Sudra a Mantra, that has the Pranava (OM) and
>   SwAhA in it, goes himself downwards and the Sudra too visits hell.
>
> **Devi YAmala Tantram**

**So, Om is a Mantra with just a single syllable and like all Mantras it will also require initiation.**

It is actually the foremost of all Mantras too and it usually sits at the front of almost all Mantras.

Any Vedic recital must also start and end with the pronunciation of Om.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Just a follow up question based on your reply. So listening to OM ok let’s say YouTube or while driving is not good ?

Comment: It's not about listening but reciting. Well if u want to follow what the scriptures say then better be initiated before reciting. Or else one can always recite the Dirgha (extended) Pranava viz-AUM (14th Sanskrit letter+the Bindu) .. This is also know as Tantrokta Pranava. There r no restrictions on it and anyone can chant it without any prohibitions. @PJai

Comment: @Rickross I think he's asking in angle while driving. Because what I was thought that certain Mantras should not be chanted while travelling because it could lead to accident!

Comment: Oh then in general Mantras shd not be chanted while on a move..@AkshayS Even while walking specially if while doing Purascharana.

Comment: Rickross Ji according to Mahabharata, Sudras meditated on Om and followed Upanishads
Hanuman says that “For all four varnas meditation (dhyana) was the main karma. Paramatma who shines like a lamp in all hearts will be the Adhishtana-Murthy for all varnas.‘Omkara’ alone was their main mantra. All four varnas followed only Upanishad Dharma.They all worshipped only the Jyoti-Swarupa Paramatma who resides in all hearts”(MB Anu 149)

Comment: When was this the case? In Satya Yuga? Or always it should be like this? @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: When they could do in one Yuga they could do in all Yugas @Rickross Ji

Comment: No that might not be true. Somethings are possible to do in Satya Yuga but not in Kali. Also I asked because the passage was in past tense. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: @Rickross It mentioned Krita Yuga

Comment: Ok, that's why I asked. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Ok you can delete now @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: You have cited Devi Yamala mantra in more than one msg. But in none of them I saw, do you mention the numbering. Could you please provide numbering ? Also, which scripture talks about the tantric pranava (AUM) you mentioned?

Comment: I have quoted from various compendium books on Tantras .. when they mention the exact locations of verses only them I would be able to provide the same .. The Tantric pranava is well known in Tantras .. Om is formed from the 13th alphabet in Sanskrit (affixed with Bindu or M) and AUM from the 14th letter .. it's called the Tantric pranava which anyone can chant but Om only Dvijas can chant. @Bingming

Comment: Yes, but could you please give one scriptural reference to me, which talks on tantric praṇava? I want to know more upon it

Comment: Also, I have heard that tantric praṇava is *hrīṁ*, instead of aum.

Comment: Hrim is the Shakta pranava .. AUM is Tantrokta pranava .. according to Mahanirvana Tantra all applications of Om should be replaced by Hrim in Kali Yuga. But AUM is different .. it is said even the uninitiates can pronounce it and get benefits out of it just like chanting Om benefits the initiates @Bingming but I will definitely let you know about scriptural references if I find them