# What happens when mantra initiation is done by an ineligible guru?

Tags: mantras, guru, siddhi, initiation

Siddhi for many mantras will happen only if the person who is reciting them undergoes initiation of mantra by a guru.

Does the siddhi of a mantra occur if initiation is done by a guru who is not eligible to initiate?

Are there any explicit statements stating about siddhi to a person who is reciting a mantra after initiation from an ineligible guru?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by ineligible here...So, in what sense you have used this word?

Comment: @Rickross Means that he is not qualified for initiation and just doing it. Like if I have just some knowledge on some mantra and then if I initiated to someone.

Comment: If he has received initiation from another Guru of that particular Sampradaya then he is qualified to initiate. Even though he might not have mastered the Mantra or he is not really a righteous person. So, basically if he himself is not initiated into that lineage he is not qualified to initiate others. Otherwise he is..

Comment: Like if I have just some knowledge on some mantra and then if I initiated to someone.   -- That won't work if u urself is not initiated into that Mantra.

Comment: @rickross Most popular mantras like "Om namo bhagwate vasudevaye" also need to be initiated by Guru first or anyone can chant? Asking coz many (me too) chants this mantra who don't even have any Guru.

Comment: Unfortunately Yes :) See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18420/4732   .. It's one of the Agamic Mantras for Vishnu. Agamas give the proper rules for reciting that Mantra. But IMO u can continue what u are doing God will take care.