What do the scriptures say about getting diksha from someone who hasn't attained mantra-siddhi?
Is it possible to attain mantra siddhi if one is going to take diksha from someone who have themselves not attained the goal of their sadhana?
Citations or examples in answers are appreciated.

Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31620/what-happens-when-mantra-initiation-is-done-by-an-ineligible-guru

@HariHara thanks for this, but that question speaks about the ineligibility of a person. Eligibility/ineligibility does not have anything to do with mantra siddhi as far as I understand.
My question is more specific to getting diksha from someone who hasn't had mantra siddhi. Eligibility is taken for granted here.

It depends on the specific Mantra. Some Mantras when chanted by someone walking the path of dharma don't wait for initiation and start giving results immediately. Mantra received from a Guru who may not have attained siddhi but is dharma-nisth still gives results and can even be perfected based on the sincerity of the chanter. In fact, if a disciple perfects it after receiving from such a Guru, even that Guru himself receives the results and himself becomes Sidh. If the initiated disciple foresakes dharma, it'll affect the Guru as well.

I) Your first question Is it possible to attain mantra siddhi if one is going to take diksha from someone who have themselves not attained the goal of their sadhana?
Answer is No, it is futile. It is like a blind leading another blind!
Seeking a Guru depends on the need.

If I want to be become a Tantri/Mantravādi,  I seek a Guru who is
competent in tantra sāstra and has accomplished mantra siddhi.
On the other hand, if I want to become a sanyāsi, then I will never
approach a tantra guru rather than seek a true sanyasi who will give me
upadesam.
Suppose I want learn Yoga, I will approach a Yoga teacher who is
skilled and knows yoga well, however he may not be aware of vedas or
puranas.

1) Kulārna Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-14] says the following regarding Guru accepting Sisya and Vice versa:
ज्ञानेन क्रियया वापि गुरु शिष्यं परीक्षयेत्‌ ।
संवत्सरं तदर्द्धं वा तदर्द्धं वा प्रयत्नतः ॥ १९ ॥ 

A Guru will test a sisya for at least 3, 6 or 12 months before
accepting him. ॥ 19 ॥

शिष्योऽपि लक्षणैरेतैः कुर्याद्‌ गुरुपरीक्षणम्‌ ।
आनन्दाद्यैर्जपस्तोत्रध्यानहोमार्चनादिषु ॥ २५ ॥
ज्ञानोपदेशसामर्थ्य मन्त्रसिद्धिमपीश्वरि ।
वेधकत्वं परिज्ञाय शिष्यो भूयान्न चान्यथा ॥ २६ ॥ 

Sisya has the right to gauge a guru through his proficiency in Japa,
Stotra, Dhyāna, Homa, Pūja and so on. After knowing his capacities for
transmission of knowledge, perfection in the science of Mantra,
ability to make subtle impact, one is to become his disciple.॥ 25-26 ॥ 

2) According to Kulārnava Tantra(कुलार्णव तंत्र) [chapter-14], there are three kinds of Dīksha (दीक्षा/Initiation) as follows:
स्पर्शाख्या देवि दृकसंज्ञा मानसाख्या महेश्वरि ।
क्रियायासादिराहता देवा दीक्षा त्रिधा स्मृता ॥ ३४ ॥ 

Initiation by touch [Sparsa], Initiation by sight [Drksamjnā] and
Initiation by thought [Mānasa] all these three are done without
Rituals and without exertions.॥ 34 ॥

According to sloka [14.34], the difference among three kinds of Dīksha is explained by subsequent three slokas [14.35-37]:

यथा पक्षी स्वपक्षाभ्यां शिशन्‌ संवर्द्धयेच्छनैः । 
स्पर्शदीक्षोपदेशच्च तादृशाः कथितः प्रिये ॥ ३५ ॥ 

O My Beloved! Initiation and instruction by touch is likened to
the slow nourishing of its young by the bird with the warmth of its
wings. ॥ 35 ॥
स्वापत्यानि यथा मत्स्यो वीक्षणेनैव पोषयेत्‌ । 
दृग्भ्यां दीक्षोपदेशश्च तादृशः परमेश्वरि ॥ ३६ ॥ 

O Paramesvari! Initiation and instruction by sight is like
nourishing of its young by the fish through its seeing alone. ॥ 36 ॥
यथा कुर्मः स्वतनयान्‌ ध्यानमात्रेण पोषयेत्‌ । 
वेधदीक्षोपदेशश्च मानसः स्यात्‌ तथाविधः ॥ ३७ ॥ 

Initiation and instruction by thought is like the nourishing of
its young by the tortoise by only thinking. ॥ 37 ॥

and 3) While initiation the disciple receives not only blessing but also sakti(शक्ति) as given in the following sloka [14.38]:
शक्तिपातानुसारेण शिष्योनुग्रहमर्हति ।
यत्र शक्ति निपातता तत्र सिद्धिर्वजायते ॥ ३८ ॥

The disciple receives the Guru according to the impact of the Sakti
[Saktipāta]; where there is no impact of Sakti there is no fulfilment.॥ 38 ॥

Beware: Unless disciple receives guru blessings with enough impact of śaktipāta(शक्तिपात/transmission or conferring of spiritual energy upon one person by another), there is no siddhi (सिद्धि/fulfilment) is possible. Here guru should be a Siddha Guru (सिद्धिगुरु) the one who is competent and already attained siddhi known as Devata Vasyam(देवता वश्यम्) or Mantra siddhi(मंत्र सिद्धि) of the concerned Devata. Those are still considered as Gurus by the standards of Kulārnava Tantra and they need not be Brahma-Jnani (ब्रह्मज्ञानी).
II) Your second and final question Citations or examples in answers are appreciated.

Just watch Sree Krishna Parunthu (ஸ்ரீகிருஷ்ண பருந்து) a 1984
Malayālam Language Movie, magnificently directed by Mr. A. Vincent,
written by Mr. P. V. Thampi and acted by Mr. Mohanlāl brilliantly as a
Tantri/Mantravādi. This movie portrays not only the role of Guru
(acted extraordinarily by Mr. Balan K. Nair) accurately but also
Guru-Shishya Parampara and how the hero of this movie acquires Mantra
Siddhi over Sri Vārthāli Tantra (श्रीवार्ताली तन्त्र) overnight,
soon after receiving a powerful mantra dīkshā from Guru, which were
depicted 100% accurately. Moreover, Mr. G. Srinivasan, who acted
effortlessly as a Dur-Mantravādi (Evil Sorcerer), practices Sri Vata
Yakshinī Tantra (श्रीवटयक्षिणी तन्त्र) and abuses the powers of
Yakshinī in order to gain supremacy over the magical powers of hero.
However, this villain was defeated finally by hero with the newly
acquired powers of Sri Vārthāli Devatha Who is more powerful than
Vata Yakshinī Devatha. All those Mantras and Dyāna Slokas chanted and used in the movie were accurate and authentic. I am sure you will
get a lot of inspiration from watching this extraordinary movie
encompassing Tantrism!

Conclusion:
Kulārna Tantra [Chapter-14] says in slokas [34] regarding three kinds of dīksa delivered without rituals and exertions as Aforementioned. These kinds of mantra dīksa(मन्त्र दीक्षा) are used for tantric upāsana(तन्तिक् उपासना) and tantra sādhana(तन्त्र​ साधना) particularly in the realm of Sākta religion. Such Gurus would be Siddha Gurus(सिद्ध गुरु) who should have already accomplished Devata-Vasyam(देवता-वश्यम्) or Mantra Siddhi(मन्त्र​ सिद्धि). These Gurus may not be Brahma-Jnanis (ब्रह्म ज्ञानि). However, it is hard to find a competent Siddha Guru rather there are plenty of charlatans, in the name of Gurus, moving around in the realm of Tantra!


Refer to Gita 4-34

Mark of Guru here https://filternet.in/index.php/%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%82

If this has already happened, then just continue sincerely.
Graceful Bhagwan will help in progress, according to merit, this birth or next. Help will arrive automatically.


